# AWS EC2 SSh Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I cannot seem to connect to my ec2 instances anymore.

To preface:

- Inbound and outbound ssh has been enabled on my security group
- A working internet gateway is attached to my VPC
- The route table is setup properly
- Basically this tutorial was followed and still nothing works

  - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

I have even destroyed my instance and created a whole new one with no luck. I was able ssh in with my first instance, then it just stopped working. Furthermore, I have tried to ssh from two separate computers, also with no luck.

Short of signing up for another AWS account I am out of things to try, Anybody have any ideas?

**SOLUTION:**
Turns out my account was in isolation mode.. My account was suspended a while ago but I had it lifted. After seeing this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/778619/network-timeout-errors-with-amazon-ec2-instance-after-first-10-minutes

I reached out to amazon and had them check if I was in *isolation*. Turns out I was. Thank you for your help in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my account was in isolation mode.. My account was suspended a while ago but I had it lifted. After seeing this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/778619/network-timeout-errors-with-amazon-ec2-instance-after-first-10-minutes

I reached out to amazon and had them check if I was in isolation. Turns out I was. Thank you for your help in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Try troubleshooting from top level architecture.

1) Check your NACL in VPC.

2) Check your route table has a internet-gateway.

3) Check if your subnet is attached with the same route table(with IGW).

4) Check your INBOUND Security Group (port 22 ssh if LINUX or RDP 3309 for Windows) to EC2 Instances. (Open SSH Inbound).

5) If your EC2 is in private subnet. Add a NAT Gateway in VPC and attach it to the route table to allow connection from Internet(0.0.0.0/0).

6) Now SSH into your EC2 Instance (if Linux) or RDP (if windows)

**Note:** Convert your pem file to ppk file if using Putty. For windows generate your password using pem in AWS console.

**For Linux:** 
Usernames for different Flavours:
amazon linux: ec2-user

ubuntu: ubuntu

Centos: ec2-user/centos

Redhat: ec2-user/root

Debian: admin/root/ec2-user

Comment: all of this has been checked out but still ssh still times out

Comment: Looks confusing...have you checked your workstation(your system) firewall settings? Open up Inbound/Outbound Ports(22,3309) and try. Can also disable firewall for trail. Recheck if you are using the correct Public IP of EC2 instance too

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as well. I suspended my account a long while ago and recently had to reactivate.

AWS support refused to investiaget my case as i don't have technical support plan on account. So I had to delete account and create another one.

This issue was also tackled in the forum here
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=356632

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found the solution, I had set up the SG port 22 with Default, Route Table and IGW was correct too. I checked my Security layer on Xfinity (my internet provider). The Firewall setting has High Security where it was blocking all except few and SSH was one of them to be blocked. I changed it to Medium where it is allowing all and blocking few.. After I changed, I was able to ssh successfully. it took me 5 hours to resolve.. Great learning. Hope this will solve yours, if you already have SG correctly set up with SSH port 22 and Route and IGS should be correct as per above comments. Enjoy AWS Cloud.. Happy Learning.